# Event Audit Trail Details are Not Getting Captured in the File which is available for Event Log Tracking on the FTP

Tags: marketing-cloud, sfmc-business-unit, eventlogfile, setup-audit-log, audit-fields

Team, let me know what actions needs to be performed in the Salesforce Marketing Cloud wherein those actions can get captured in the Event Log File which is available on the FTP.

Currently, when I tried changing the Session Timeout Value in the Security Settings of the SFMC. Then, it got captured in the Activity Log file instead of the Event Log file.

Can any one help me with the actions that will get captured in the Event Log File ?

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation, here are the events captured in the Security Event Audit Log:

```
1   Login Attempted
2   Security Question Answered  
3   Password Changed    
4   Administrator Access (Support person has impersonated into the user account.)
5   Administrator Unlock (Logged when Administrator unlocks a user.)
6   Redirect (For users provisioned with IMH Redirect flow, this means that the user is redirected to CAS pages and they try to login from Members.)
7   Security Setting Changed Impersonation
8   Logout  
9   Request Authorization Code  
10  Request Token
```

**References:**

- [Security Event Audit Log](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_security_event_audit_trail.htm&type=5)
- [Security Action Audit Log](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_security_action_audit_trail.htm&type=5)
- [Audit Trail](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_overview_audit_trail.htm&type=5)
- [Create an Audit Trail Data Extract Activity](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_create_an_audit_trail_data_extract_activity.htm&type=5)

Comment: Okay... So may I know like once I will do the modifications mentioned by you then when that is supposed to get reflected/captured in the file on the FTP ? (i.e., how much duration it will take to get reflected in the file)

Consider, today I changed the password at 2:00 PM (IST). Then, when should we expect the outcome of that change in the event log file on the FTP ?

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: How often are you running the extract? And you would need to run it at the EID level